# Python relative path problems

Tags: python, path, directory

I am trying to create some helper functions that will give me a folder based on the relative paths:

```
def get_BASE_dir_path():
    cur_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    BASE  = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cur_dir,"..",".."))
    return BASE

def get_src_dir_path():
    BASE = get_BASE_dir_path()
    src_dir  = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE,"src"))
    return src_dir

def get_lib_dir_path():
    BASE = get_BASE_dir_path()
    lib_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(BASE,"src","lib"))
    return lib_dir

def get_ffmpeg_dir_path():
    BASE = get_BASE_dir_path()
    ffmpeg_dir= os.path.dirname(os.path.join(BASE,"src","lib","ffmpeg"))
    return ffmpeg_dir
```

But, somehow, I am not getting the right results when I print the functions:

Output:

```
C:\dev\project
C:\dev\project\src
C:\dev\project\src
C:\dev\project\src\lib
```

What did I miss?

Comment: And what, relative to `dev\project` is the *expected* path then? Where is the file with these functions located?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't output anything... Also avoid using `'..'` to mean parent directory, because that's not portable. Use `os.path.pardir` instead.

Comment: Your `get_lib_dir_path` and `get_ffmpeg_dir_path` return *directory names*, so `'c:\\dev\\project\\src'` and `'c:\\dev\\project\\src\\lib'`, respectively; you used the wrong function name there.

Comment: In the last two instead of getting the base directory get the `src` directory and simply join the additional values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here, in function get_lib_dir_path()

```
lib_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(BASE,"src","lib"))
```

It should be:

```
lib_dir = os.path.join(BASE,"src","lib")
```

The same thing happens in get_ffmpeg_dir_path(). By calling dirname(), you chop off the last directory.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because you are returning dirname instead of abspath for the last two values.